# batch script - run program on each file in directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, foreach

I need to run a program that takes an .inp file and gives a .log file, on a big number of files. 
 
 In each directory (with a specific name) there are 2 files, with the same name for each directory:  *dft_opt.inp* and *dft_nmr.inp* and they have to be used in this order because the second needs data from the first output.
In the command line the program works like 
`orca dft_opt.inp > dft_opt.log`  
 
I'm struggling with the batch script because of the precise order needed.
This is my best attempt.

```
for %%d in (*/orca_input); 
do (cd "%%d" & runningprogram); 
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first time. I think now is better. I looked up for answered questions but found none with a specific order.

Comment: "I'm struggling with the batch script bacause of the precise order needed."  What batch script?  You have failed to post an [mcve].  Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. [Edit] your post to include your best attempt so far.

Comment: Included my attempt and edited.

Comment: Why are you trying to sort, or get files into an order? You've only got two target files in each directory, and each of those, you've already told us, has exactly the same names! The information you've provided also clearly shows us the command you're trying to run against one file, `dft_opt.inp`, but not what you're doing with `dft_nmr.inp`. Your provided code isn't even close to the correct syntax. To find out how to use each command, open up a Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`, window, and enter either `help command` or `command /?`, e.g. `help for` or `for /?`.

Comment: Ok I see, since they have the same name I can just use their names. Sorry for the bad syntax, I'm new to CMD I thought was better understand the logic and then work on the syntax, it should be ok now I think. With the other file I'm doing the same. Now that you showed me it was trivial, should I delete the post and ask another question on how to run that specific program in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (

    rem Check if orca_input subfolder exist.
    if exist "%%~A\orca_input\" (

        rem Check if dft_opt.inp and dft_nmr.inp files exist.
        if exist "%%~A\orca_input\dft_opt.inp" if exist "%%~A\orca_input\dft_nmr.inp" (

            rem Change working directory to where the files are temporarily.
            pushd "%%~A\orca_input" && (

                rem Run the program.
                orca dft_opt.inp > dft_opt.log
                orca dft_nmr.inp > dft_nmr.log
                popd
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This code works on the example structure from command `tree /a /f`:

> ```
> +---a
> |   \---orca_input
> |           dft_nmr.inp
> |           dft_opt.inp
> |
> \---b
>     \---orca_input
>             dft_nmr.inp
>             dft_opt.inp
> ```

Folders `a` and `b` are iterated by the 1st for loop. `orca_input` is checked if `exist`. if does exist, check if both files of `dft_opt.inp` and `dft_nmr.inp` exist. If does exist, change directory to the directory of the files and run the program `orca` on those files and redirect output to the log file.

Comment: Thanks I understood structure and logic :) Now I will study the syntax by my own.